# MySql Where and And Statement throws error in Join

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the below statement

```
SELECT ORDER_MONTH,
SUM(PRICE) as Price    
FROM  (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ORDERDATE) AS ORDER_YEAR,    
MONTHNAME(ORDERDATE) AS ORDER_MONTH,        
ORDERDATE, PRICE  FROM ORDER_ABSTRACT)A
WHERE ORDER_YEAR=2016 AND SKU=4567 
GROUP BY MONTH(ORDERDATE)
```

Its throwing error as unknown column 'SKU'

Table Description

```
 Name Type Collation Attributes Null Default Extra
1 ID varchar(36) utf8_general_ci No None
2 InvoiceNo varchar(20) utf8_general_ci No None
3 RefRetailer varchar(36) utf8_general_ci No None
4 SKU varchar(20) utf8_general_ci No None
5 OrderDate date No None
6 CurrentStatus varchar(10) utf8_general_ci No None
7 Price double No None
8 PaymentType varchar(10) latin1_swedish_ci No None
```

Comment: please show your database tables structure

Comment: i think SKU should be with single quote, like: 

SKU='4567'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see an inner join but a dinamically created temp table  and in this 
You don't have a column sku

could be you  need also SKU in subselect

```
SELECT ORDER_MONTH,
SUM(PRICE) as Price    
FROM  ( SELECT SKU,
               EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ORDERDATE) AS ORDER_YEAR,    
               MONTHNAME(ORDERDATE) AS ORDER_MONTH,        
               ORDERDATE, 
               PRICE  
      FROM ORDER_ABSTRACT) A
WHERE ORDER_YEAR=2016 
AND SKU='4567' 
GROUP BY MONTH(ORDERDATE)
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by didn't work. SKU clearly should have a comma after it and my personal preference is to qualify items returned by a sub query with the sub query alias.

Comment: @JijoNair  i have update the asnwer  with the missing comma and quote around sku value. looking at your table schema .. do the fact you use a subquery in this subquery you must select SKU  too..

Comment: yes.. But I think I got the answer too..Looking to my query and yours..would you tell that that not seleting SKU in the outer query would work?

Comment: @JijoNair   Your external query select value from the table A. The table A is only  the result of the subquery ..if you don't select the column SKU in subqery you can't select the column SKU from the table A and for this you can't use the column SKU in where condition ..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that a sub query is required - you could rewrite something line below

```
SELECT  case
                when month(orderdate) = 1 then 'Jan'
                when month(orderdate) = 2 then 'Feb'
                when month(orderdate) = 3 then 'Mar'
                when month(orderdate) = 4 then 'Apr'
                when month(orderdate) = 5 then 'May'
                when month(orderdate) = 6 then 'Jun'
                when month(orderdate) = 7 then 'Jul'
                when month(orderdate) = 8 then 'Aug'
                when month(orderdate) = 9 then 'Sep'
                when month(orderdate) = 10 then 'Oct'
                when month(orderdate) = 11 then 'Nov'
                when month(orderdate) = 12 then 'Dec'
            end ordermonth
                ,SUM(PRICE) as Price    
FROM    order_abstract
WHERE   year(ORDERdate) = 2016 AND SKU=4567 
GROUP BY MONTH(ORDERDATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT SKU, ORDER_MONTH,
    SUM(PRICE) as Price
    FROM (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ORDERDATE) AS ORDER_YEAR,
                 SKU,
                 MONTHNAME(ORDERDATE) AS ORDER_MONTH, 
                 ORDERDATE, 
                 PRICE FROM ORDER_ABSTRACT )A 
    WHERE ORDER_YEAR=2016 AND SKU = 'AHMD1234' 
    GROUP BY SKU,MONTH(ORDERDATE)
```

This solved my problem.